# Need to prove a function is one-to-one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Can anyone help me to prove that the function $f:\{x\in \mathbb{Q}|x\leq0\}\to\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x-2}$ is one-to-one (injective)?

Many thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? There are several ways to approach this.

Comment: I tried contradiction and similar stuff. I got a weird solution with a friend but it seemed very messy...

Comment: Have you studied calculus? Or just algebra?

Comment: I have studied a very basic part of calculus but I shouldn't really use it in this solution. I should only use sets, functions and obviously the definition of an injective function.

Comment: I'd like to give a hint for a solution just using algebra, but your question was already answered.

Comment: Haha, thanks anyways! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x,y\le0$ and $x\ne y$. If $f(x)=f(y)$, then

\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{x-2}&=\frac{y^2}{y-2}\\
x^2y-2x^2&=xy^2-2y^2\\
xy(x-y)-2(x-y)(x+y)&=0\\
(x-y)(xy-2x-2y)&=0
\end{align}

Since $x\ne y$, $xy-2x-2y=0$. But this is impossible as $xy\ge0$ and $x+y<0$ (Note that $x\ne y$ implies that $x$ and $y$ cannot be both zero).

This leads to a contradiction.

$f$ is injective.

Comment: Beautiful proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach
$$ f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x-2}=\frac{(x-2)^2+4x-4}{x-2}=x-2+4*\frac{x-1}{x-2} $$for x<0
Now if x is increasing so does x-2 and (x-1)/(x-2)
So f is increasing so f injective

Comment: It is not obvious that $\frac{x-1}{x-2}$ is an increasing function for $x<0$. Can you justify that in your answer?

Comment: It  is the same to show that for x>0 $$\frac{x+1}{x+2} $$  is increasing which is obvious